# How to animate a single item from Flatlist array in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, animation

I have a array of data which I render in flatlist in React-Native. When I press a single item I only want to animate it.. I'm bit confused and cant fix how I can animate it.. Can anyone show it and explain it please? Because I couldnt find any explanation which is explained with Flatlist rendering..

```
   constructor(props){ 
super(props); 
this.state = { animation: new Animated.Value(1) }


startAnimation (x){
        Animated.timing(this.state.animation, {
            toValue: 1.5,
            duration: 1500
        }).start();
    }


 _renderItem = ({item, index}) => {

        return(
            <Animated.View key={index} style={{margin: 10, transform:[{scale: this.state.animation}]}}>
                <TouchableOpacity onLongPress={() => this.activateItem(item.id)} onPress={() => this.startAnimation(index)}>
                    <Image source={ images[item.item_id].uri } style={{width: 60, height: 60}}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </Animated.View>
        );

    };



 render(){
        return(

            <View style={{flex: 1}}>

                <FlatList
                      numColumns={4}
                      data={this.state.items}
                      renderItem={this._renderItem}
                      keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
                      extraData={this.state.animation}
                />

            </View>

        );
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you could make a listItem component and inside that component configure your animation, instead of configuring your animations in parent component

Comment: If you think it would work, can you write for me a small example please? So I can approve it as answer then if it will work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is isolated the item and animation state in another component then each item will have your own animation and when this item was clicked only him will be animated!
[see this example working](http://snack.expo.io/BJBYZqPE7)

Comment: could you write it as code with small example.. so it will be much more understandable

Comment: It looks like it works, wait I will check and tell you totally. Yeah I checked it works very nice! Thank you mate.. For newbies and people like its sometimes hard to understand these easy stuff.. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Maybe add it to your answer, so people who will read it will easily understand it from code instead of checking link. Also you can attach the link as well in your answer.